# Any better way to handle overwhelming heading data from CLLocationManager to present on UI?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cllocationmanager

I can fetch Heading data from CLLocationManager.

```
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.headingFilter = 0.2
    locationManager.headingOrientation =  CLDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    locationManager.delegate = self
```

I can use

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    let headingDegree = newHeading.trueHeading
    // Keep update CALayer
    scrollLayer.scroll(to: CGPoint(x: headingDegree, y: 20.0))
}
```

to update UI. The UI is a heading tap on the top of a CAScrollLayer.

### Problem:

The heading tape keeps shaking when the iPhone yawing too fast. I believe the scrolling activity is not quick enough to process overwhelming heading data.

### Question:

Is there any better way to handle heading update data with CAScrollLayer?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need some smoothing in place. To be clear, smoothing (in it's most basic form) is taking an average value over time. Let's say that you want to take the average value over the last 60 or so updates then you would have an array of values which you use to calculate the average:

```
var arr: [Double] = []

func average(latestVal: Double) -> Double
{
    if arr.count >= 60 {
        arr.remove(at: 0)
    }
    arr.append(latestVal)

    let total = arr.reduce(0, { $0 + $1 })

    return total / Double(arr.count)
}
```

This really is the perfect opportunity to implement a queue in Swift which you can find details on [here](http://ericasadun.com/2016/03/08/swift-queue-fun/).